# I don't understand code behaviour

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I have the folowing code:

```
from random import randint
from medical_room import *
from Library import *
from basement import *
from End import *

class start_Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
       print "You landed on planet and see three rooms."
       print "You approach and see that you need to enter password..."
       self.door=raw_input("Pick number of door>>>")
       self.password=('%d')%(randint(1,9))
       self.entered_password=int(raw_input("Enter password of one digit>>>"))
       self.ROOMs={'1':Medical_room,'2':Library,'3':basement,'4':End}
       while True:
 #            break
            room=self.ROOMs[self.door]
 #            print room()
            self.door=room()

a=start_Game()
```

When asked about door number I pick '1' and class `Medical_room` is launched (code of class is below):

```
class Medical_room(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.play()

    def play(self):
         print "Medical_room plays"
         return '2'
```

But I can't switch to `Library` class since get error:

```
room=self.ROOMs[self.door]
KeyError: <medical_room.Medical_room object at 0x0000000002906978>
```

For me everything is ok, but Python doesn't like my 'great logic'. Please help.

Comment: Python isn't Java. You don't have to shoehorn everything into a class. Specifically, if a class has no methods other than `__init__`, it can probably be defined as a function instead.

Comment: Please get rid of those *-imports. You're cluttering your namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Before the loop runs, `self.door` is a string. On the first iteration of the loop, you set `self.door` as a reference to an object on the first iteration. On the second iteration, you try to use that object as a key on `self.ROOMS`, but that dictionary has only strings for keys.

You need to set `self.door` to the string returned by `play`, I believe:

```
while True:
    room=self.ROOMs[self.door]
    self.door=room().play()
```

However, this doesn't allow you to choose a new door in each room (unless you change the definition of `play`).

Comment: How can I in this situation make class start_Game switch between different classes?

Comment: This is probably a better question for codereview.stackexchange.com. Your program needs a large amount of redesign, which I think is beyond the scope of this site.